# img class affect every image and repalces other images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm baffled and confused. In the code below I have a hover image that changes from red to blue at the bottom. The thing is. Having added this code it also replicates in the img class near the top of the page. How can I separate the two img? Why does the lower image affect the one higher up? Any answers would be most welcome

```
<

!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>Web Development Sevenoaks Kent - Web Design Sevenoaks Kent</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Web Development and Design in Sevenoaks Kent - DP Web Development based in Sevenoaks Kent ">
<meta name="keywords" content="Web Development, Bespoke Website Design, Sevenoaks, Kent, Website Maintenance, Website ">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.dpwebdevelopment.co.uk" />

<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dpwebdevelopment4.css">


<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.dpwebdevelopment.co.uk/favicon.ico"/>


</head>
<body>

<?php require_once('nav.php'); ?>
    <div id="bgleft"></div>
    <div id="bgright"></div>


<img class="displayed"  alt='DP Web Development Sevenoaks Kent Logo' src='webdevelopmentimages/DPLogo1.jpg' > 

<div id="portrait">
<img  src='webdevelopmentimages/Doug-Pitchers.jpg' alt='Doug Pitchers owner of DP Web Development'>
</div> 


    <main>


<div id="quote1">
<h1>Your website is not <i>just</i> a website...<br></h1></div>
<div id="quote2">
             <h1>it's the best damn salesperson you'll ever have.</h1>
</div>

<div id="moveup">
<P class="blocktext">Whether you're a cocky upstart, a confident entrepreneur or a knarled old pro<b> one thing's for sure:</b>
</div>

<div id="quote3">
A professional outfit needs a professional web developer.
</div>

<p class="blocktext"><b>and you know you need a web developer that:</b></p>
<div id="list">
<ul>
         <li>totally "gets” you</li>
         <li>is jargon free! describes things in plain English</li>
         <li>gets back to you promptly</li>
         <li>hits deadlines. Every time.</li>
         <li>makes the project fun!</li>
         </ul>

</div>

<p class="blocktext"><b>You deserve a website thet will help you:</b></p>
<div id="list">
<ul>
        <li>Look good</li>
        <li>Showcase the results of your (extremely) hard work</li>
        <li>Impress clients - even when you're asleep</li>
        <li>Be seen as <b>the expert</b> in your field</li>
        <li>Be seen as cutting edge in your niche</li>
</ul>
</div>


<p class="blocktext"><b>and you won't have to lift a finger to get it</b></p>
<div id="list">
<ul>
        <li>You don't need to worry about the coding - <b>It's sorted</b></li>
        <li>You don't need to worry about the domain - <b>It's sorted</b></li>
        <li>You don't need to worry about the hosting - <b>It's sorted</b></li>
        <li>You don't need to worry about the launch - <b>It's sorted</b></li>
        <li>You don't need to worry about the process - <b>It's sorted</b></li>
        </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div id="quote3">
This means you can RELAX: a new, gleaming and slick website is on it's way! 
</div>

<div id="offer">
<p><b>But that's not all,</b> FOR FREE you get:</p>
</div>
<div id="list">
<ul>
     <li><b>Google Analytics:</b> You will be able to see who, where, how much and how long poeple stay on your site. you'' be able to see what they are doing on your site and you can compare reasutls with other times of the year. And loads more besides. Pretty much everyting you would want to know about visits to your website.</li>
     <li><b>Five new email addresses:</b> Because you@hotmail doesn't cut it anymore.  And you get </b>five</b>. For different people in the business. Different areas of the business. Or just to look damn good.</li>
     <li><b>All hosting costs, domain name purchases:</b>There are never any nasty surprises. Ever. The price quoted is the price you pay. It will never rise. Oh and I don't quote prices "+ VAT". Why do people do that? All prices are final.</li>
     <li><b>I will promote your website</b> on Facebook, Twitter and my own website for one month. Totally free publity! Need I say more?</li>
</ul>
</div>


<script src="_js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="button1">
<script>
var a = [];

a[0] = "webdevelopmentimages/BUTTON2.gif";
a[1] = "webdevelopmentimages/BUTTON6.gif";


$(document).ready(function() {
  var source = $.preload(a); 
  $('img').attr('src',source[0].src); //just an acknowledgement (pre-loading done)
  $('img').hover(function() {
    $('img').attr('src',source[1].src);
  },function() {
    $('img').attr('src',source[0].src);    
  });

});



//Image Preloading....  
var cache = [];
  $.preload = function(arr) {
    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = arr[i];
      cache.push(img);
    }
    return cache;
  };


</script>

<img  />
</div>


<div id="emailbackground">
<div id="email">
<p>Enter your email below and feel empowered:<br>
Get help to make sense of the (digital) world
and look way more knowledgeable<br>
you'll never have to bluff your way again.</br>
<div id="emailbig">
+  get great entrepreneurial advice for <b>free!</b></p>


<div class="login">
<form  method="post" action="http://ymlp.com/subscribe.php?id=gbjmeqmgmgj" target="signup_popup" onsubmit="window.open( 'http://ymlp.com/subscribe.php?id=gbjmeqmgmgj','signup_popup','scrollbars=yes,width=600,height=450'); return true;"> 




E-mail address:
<input name="YMP0" size="20" type="text">


Name:
<input name="YMP8" size="20" type="text">

<div class="login">
<input value="Submit" type="submit">
</div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</main>


</body>`
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you need to put limits on your selectors. The code

```
$("img")
```

...finds **all** `img` elements in the DOM. And this code:

```
$('img').attr('src',source[1].src);
```

...sets `src` on **all** `img` elements in the DOM. You need to narrow that scope.

It's not clear to me which specific image you want to work on, but if it doesn't already have some `id` or `class` value that only it has, you'll want to add one. Then either use

```
$("#the-id")
```

or

```
$("img.the-class")
```

...to refer to it and set its `src`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're calling all of the images every time. Change

```
$('img').hover(function() {
    $('img').attr('src',source[1].src); // affects all images
  },function() {
    $('img').attr('src',source[0].src);    
  });
```

to this (excuse the pun) -

```
 $('img').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src',source[1].src); // affects only this image
  },function() {
    $(this).attr('src',source[0].src);    
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a cssclass for the second image and use the class in jQuery to change the source.....if you use the 'img' in your jQuery it will affect all img tags. Do this:

add class="secondimageclass" to your second image HTML and change your script to use the class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var source = $.preload(a); 
$('.secondimageclass').attr('src',source[0].src); //just an acknowledgement (pre-loading done)
$('.secondimageclass').hover(function() {
$('.secondimageclass').attr('src',source[1].src);
},function() {
   $('.secondimageclass').attr('src',source[0].src);    
});

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help....i have 6 images (so far there may be more). Would this need to be done for every image ?  T be clear I change the 2nd HTML class from "dynamic-content" to secondimage class? sorry if I am slow but how do i change the source?. it si where it is? Does the fact I am on WordPress platform make a difference?